# Error, trigger instead of is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I try to create an instead of trigger. Its purpose it's to insert in 3 tables instead of a view that i have, but I have a series of problems.

```
Create or replace trigger trigg_view
Instead of Insert ON Carti_Beletristica
for each row

Begin

dbms_output.put_line('i dont know');

End;
```

This is the very basic code from which i want to start.  It let me Create it, but when i try an insert in my view (Carti_Beletristica) i get the next error

```
ORA-04098: trigger 'RO_A372_SQL_S20.INSERT_VIEW_TRIGG' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

This is very frustrating because it is a very simple trigger and I can't continue... After that, how I will generate de primary keys ? Because in the view i dont have something like that. My idea was to select the max from the primary keys in a table, then add one, then use this value, but i get a lot of errors.

```
CREATE VIEW Carti_Beletristica AS
SELECT titlu, nr_pagini, nr_exemplare, nume AS autor, telefon
FROM Carte NATURAL JOIN Autor JOIN Persoana ON (id_pers = id_aut)
WHERE upper(gen) = 'BELETRISTICA'
```

This is the view.

```
Create table Persoana(
    id_pers number(10) not null,
    nume varchar2(100) not null,
    telefon varchar2(15) not null,

    Constraint persoana_id_pers_pk primary key(id_pers)
 );

Create table Carte(
    id_carte number(10) not null,
    titlu varchar2(100) not null,
    nr_pagini number(10) not null,
    nr_exemplare number(10) not null,
    gen varchar2(20) not null,

    Constraint carte_id_carte_pk primary key(id_carte)  
 );

Create table Autor(
    id_carte number(10) not null,
    id_aut number(10) not null,

    Constraint autor_pk primary key(id_carte,id_aut),

    Constraint autor_id_carte_fk foreign key(id_carte) references Carte(id_carte),
    Constraint autor_id_aut_fk foreign key(id_aut) references Persoana(id_pers)
```

);

Can you help me out a bit ? An insert on the view would look like that

```
Insert into Carti_Beletristica(titlu,nr_pagini,nr_exemplare,autor,telefon)
values('tiltu',69,96,'otor','07phonenumber')
```

EDIT:

This is what I tried for the primary key

```
Create or replace trigger trigg_view
Instead of Insert ON Carti_Beletristica
for each row
declare
    aux persoana.id_pers%type;
Begin

    select max(id_pers)+1 into aux from Persoana;

    dbms_output.put_line(aux);

End;
```

Comment: Regarding your first error, it looks like you have more than one trigger on the view. The one you've shown is valid but it looks like there's another invalid one that's causing your error.  (Try `DROP TRIGGER INSERT_VIEW_TRIGG` to get rid of the invalid one.)  Also, later on you write that you 'get a lot of errors'.  What errors?  Please edit your question to include the errors you get.

Comment: *"how I will generate de primary keys ?"* - You may use 3 sequences for each table and insert `table_sequence.nextval` in your Trigger. This is if you are  on Oracle 11 or prior versions. For 12c and above use [IDENTITY](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1) columns

Comment: Ok. @Luke Woodward  helped me get this right so i could finish all the code.
KaushikNayak I understood nothing from what u said, but my idea worked.
Thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My idea was to select the max from the primary keys in a table, then add one, then use this value,

You may think *"my idea worked"* but this is very bad practice:

```
select max(id_pers)+1 into aux from Persoana;
```

This is an inefficient way of getting a primary key identifier. More importantly it is **unsafe** because it won't work in multi-user environments: two users inserting into that table at the same time will derive the same "next value" (because of read-commit isolation) then one of those user will get a duplicate key violation when they commit their transaction.

The correct solution is to use Oracle's built-in unique key generators. Prior to 12c that meant a sequence. For your `persoana` table that would mean creating a sequence called `persoana_seq` that you would reference in your trigger as :

```
aux := persoana_seq.nextval;
```

Sequences are the most performative mechanism for generating a series of **guaranteed unique** numbers.

In Oracle 12c we can define columns as IDENTITY columns. This provides us with an auto-incrementing column :

```
create table persoana (
       id generated always as identity primary key,
       ....
```

`persoana.id` will be populated with a unique value automatically on insert, without any further action on our part. (Identity columns have associated sequences under the covers, it's just we don't need to worry about them.)